# Assert type for code completion in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, ide, rubymine, code-completion

Ruby isn't a statically-typed language, so it isn't really possible for a code completion engine to know *exactly* what type any function will return.

However, sometimes the programmer knows. Take the code below, which uses metaprogramming to 'confuse' code completion:

```
class Example
  define_method :foo do
    2 + 2
  end

  def bar
    foo_result = foo
  end
end
```

A static analyser doesn't know that `foo` exists, so it can't provide code completion for it. Even though `foo` will always be an `Integer` and we know that, I only get code completion for `BasicObject`.

[image]

Is there a way to tell a code completion engine which type I know something is going to be, so that I get better completion results, which is simply ignored by the interpreter?

Comment: But do we actually "know that" in ruby? [We Know Nothing](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/TiskTisk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is *partially* possible using "Annotations" in the form of comments, which are documented at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-annotations.html

You can add types to ambiguous methods or variables like this:

```
# @return [String]
def mystery_method
    # @type [Integer]
    foo = nil
end
```

It doesn't appear that you can create entirely new methods using this approach though, for example for metaprogramming-driven methods.